# I have Some Problem retrieving information from ldap

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I have installed openldap from symas on centos 8,

- I modified **/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}mdb.ldif**
  by adding the following

  **olcRootPW: {SSHA}......etc** line to make a password
- modified the slapd configuration file to be  :

  ```
  **BASE    dc=example**

  **URI     ldap://localhost:389**
  ```
- added the following file :

**SampleOrganization.ldif**

```
dn : dc=example

objectclass : domain

dc : example

dn : ou=Accountants,dc=example

objectClass : organizationalUnit

ou : Accountants

dn : ou=Engineers,dc=example

objectClass : organizationalUnit

ou : Engineers
```

---

on the terminal I run :

**ldapadd -x  -c -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"  -H ldap://localhost:389 -f SampleOrganization.ldif**

Then entered the password ... it seems the object is added  because no error appeared

Now the problem when trying to search nothing is retrieved using :

**ldapsearch  -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"  -H ldap://127.0.0.1:389  -b "ou=Engineers,dc=example" "Smith"**

---

I would like to mention after some search i tried **slapcat** it gave the following Error :

```
6031b551 ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif"
6031b551 ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}mdb.ldif"
6031b551 The first database does not allow slapcat; using the first available one (2)
```

---

I am so much confused what could be the reason for that i have some doubt it may be the checksum error but if so how to fix it?

nothing is retrieved giving the following :

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I modified /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}mdb.ldif

The files of back-config are not edited like regular text files. You have to use ldapadd, ldapmodify to send LDAP write operations for modifying the config.

> `6031b551 ldif_read_file: checksum error on`

This is the result of manually modifying LDIF files of back-config.